# using "find -exec grep" in MingW

Tags: find, mingw

I'm having trouble doing simple searches in MingW.
The following query works:

```
find 'C:/Dir' -iname '*foo*'
```

but the query

```
find 'C:/Dir' -iname '*foo*' -exec grep bar {} \;
```

fails.

Can anyone point me to the proper syntax for this command being run under MingW in a powershell?

PS: My apologies the error message I get is "missing argument to -exec".

Comment: When using paths with backslashes in MSYS shell make sure to use single quotes, not double quotes.

Comment: It's not the double quotes ( which I mistyped here ) . It is the argument to exec which is causing the problem.

Comment: Have you tried `';'` instead of `\;`?